# React Hooks not updating array correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of variables and an index variable, represented by a "#" symbol. I am trying to implement a delete method, which will remove the character to the left of the "#" character in the array.

For example,

```
myArray = ["A", "B", "C", "#"]
index = 3
```

call delete function

```
myArray = ["A", "B", "#"]
index = 2
```

however, it is not updating the array properly with the new values, it is simply swapping the positions of the "#" character with the character to its left. I suspect this is because when I am calling my delete function, I am calling my useState hook twice successively. Is this the reason, and if so, how can I resolve it? Here is my code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-tree-378p4

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [variables, updateVariables] = useState(["A", "B", "C", "#"]);
  const [index, updateIndex] = useState(3);

  const decrementIndex = (c = 1) => updateIndex(i => i - c);

  const swap = (array, i, j) => {
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
    return array;
  };

  const moveCursorLeft = () => {
    if (!(index === 0)) {
      swap(variables, index, index - 1);
      updateVariables(variables);
      decrementIndex();
    }
  };

  const deleteCharacter = () => {
    const head = variables.slice(0, index - 1);
    const tail = variables.slice(index, variables.length);
    updateVariables(oldVariables => {
      let newVariables = [...oldVariables];
      newVariables = head.concat(tail);
      return newVariables;
    });
    moveCursorLeft();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }}
        onClick={() => deleteCharacter()}
      />
      <span>
        {variables.map(v => (
          <var> {v} </var>
        ))}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why all the moving parts to remove an element from an array by index? What is the purpose of `moveCursorLeft` after deleting a character?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need for the `moveCursorLeft` function. By slicing in `deleteCharacter`, you have already shifted it left.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [variables, updateVariables] = useState(["A", "B", "C", "#"]);
  const [index, updateIndex] = useState(3);

  const decrementIndex = (c = 1) => updateIndex(i => i - c);

  const deleteCharacter = () => {
    updateVariables(oldVariables => [
      ...oldVariables.slice(0, index - 1),
      ...oldVariables.slice(index)
    ]);
    decrementIndex();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }}
        onClick={() => deleteCharacter()}
      />
      <span>
        {variables.map(v => (
          <var> {v} </var>
        ))}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```